# Generate RDLC report for list of persons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

it's a kind of letter that i should generate for all customer in the application, the header contain information of customer and the body contain the letter and some customer details.
for one customer it's simple but when i come to the generation of this letter to all customer it gets little bit complicated.
Any help will be so much appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: I couldn't understand your requirement clearly. Do you mean you want to generate the report for the user? One user should contains its own information? Could you please post a image about which result you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBjhq.png)
i want to generate this letter for multiple application users